# Short story about creating a fake alien to scare people into cleaning up Earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, alien-invasion

Earth has a serious pollution problem. Story is about a small group (couple?) of humans who create a simulacrum of an alien disguised in the body of a human. Purpose is to have it discovered and examined to show that aliens are secretly polluting Earth to make it more suitable for alien takeover.
Hopefully this will cause humans to reduce Earth pollution.

Comment: Roughly when would this have been written? Was it part of an anthology, if so which other stories were in it and what did the cover look like?

Answer (score 11):

This is "Occam's Scalpel" by Theodore Sturgeon, also the answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110564/looking-for-the-name-of-a-short-story-about-a-fake-alien-autopsy-used-to-change/110565#110565).

From my description there:

> Two brothers, one a maker of medical dummies and the other the personal physician to the aging boss of a multinational company, stage a fake autopsy to convince the boss's anointed successor that he was actually a sulphur-breathing alien who wanted to pollute the atmosphere to make it more suitable for the rest of his species.

Comment: Ike, if this is the right answer, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left. Please do; it will show everyone the mystery was solved, and reward both you and Daniel with some reputation :)